# Get filereader result in nextjs Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, javascript-objects, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement image preview before file upload in NextJs. When I read the result and try to display it doesn't work as usual. The image breaks. I have added the code below. Any inputs appreciated to sort this problem.

**Edit:** Partially solved this by converting the buffer to blob url. It works perfectly with img tag but next/image still doesn't support blob urls.

**code**

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import Image from 'next/image';
import australia from '../public/images/australia.png';

const Create: React.FC<{ onClose: () => void }> = ({ onClose }) => {
    
    const [uploadedImage, setUploadedImage] = React.useState<any>();
    
    const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
        acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
            const reader = new FileReader()
    
            reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
            reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
            reader.onload = () => {
                // Do whatever you want with the file contents
                const binaryStr = reader.result
                //changed this to blob url working perfectly with img tag not with Image tag.
                setUploadedImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
                }
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
            })
        }, []);
    return (
            <>
               <div {...getRootProps()} className="p-7 border-2 border-dashed my-5 focus:border-indigo-500">
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                {
                    isDragActive ?
                        <p>Drop the files here...</p> : <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
                }
                </div>
                <img src={uploadedImage || '/images/australia.png'} />
            </>
    );
```

**Error Console**
[image: error description after image upload]

Comment: You seem to be reading the content of a file and then trying to use the content as a url. It might be possible to do that on some browsers, but I just want to double-check: is that what you want to do?

Comment: @EmilKarlsson I am just trying to display the image of the uploaded file. But the nextjs image is treating the data as url source. I had it worked in React but nextjs has an issue that I am unable to figure out.

Comment: No, you are treating the data as url source. "<img src={uploadedImage || '/images/australia.png'} />". You are literally telling the app to use uploadedImage as the source ("src").

Comment: @EmilKarlsson partially solved this by changing the way file is read I will update the code above.

Comment: @SriharshaK What Next.js version are you on? `next/image` supports `blob:` object URLs since [`v11.1.1`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v11.1.1).

Comment: you're doing it right, but instead of  "<img src={uploadedImage || '/images/australia.png'} />" use " {uploadedImage && <Image src={uploadedImage} alt={'imageAlt'} width="24" height="24" />}" it should work now, make sure to import Image from next/image like "import Image from 'next/image'". you may also need to add "localhost:3000" in your next.config.js inside domains attribute. i have tested this next12.